# Adding observations in a table and attribute a given observation (join)

Tags: r, date, join

Good afternoon,

I'm analyzing the distribution of observations in a given month, for example:

Date Observations

2010-01 10

2010-03 15

2010-05 16

Question: How do I insert the missing dates (2010-02 and 2010-05) in the table (using other table with all the monthly dates) and attribute a 0 as observations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We convert the 'Date' to `Date` class, then use `complete` expand the dataset by getting the sequence of `min/max` or `first`, `last` 'Date' `by` '1 month' while `fill`ing the 'Observations' with 0

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
     complete(Date = seq(first(Date), last(Date), by = '1 month'), 
            fill = list(Observations = 0))
```

---

If there is another dataset with complete 'Date', then the obvious option is a `left_join` and then replace the `NA` elements in 'Observations' with 0 because by default if we don't have a match, it will be filled with `NA`

```
left_join(df2, df1, by = 'Date') %>%
     mutate(Observations = replace_na(Observations, 0))
```

NOTE: `df2` is the dataset with complete 'Date'

In case, if the 'df2' have other columns as well, we don't need to `select` those columns

```
left_join(df2 %>% 
               select(Date), df1) %>%
     mutate(Observations = replace_na(Observations, 0))
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `merge`

```
transform(merge(df2, df1, by = 'Date', all.x = TRUE),
      Observations = replace(Observations, is.na(Observations), 0))
```